# How does arithmetic sequence of addition with SUM works in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, math, sum, floating-point, aggregate

I have an issue with the `SUM` operation on float data type on SQL Server 2016. I know addition with float data type is not associative means, so the order of additions matters and it will affect the accuracy of the result. However, it is just makes me wonder, how does `SUM` work? I can't find any materials that tells me about its arithmetic sequence and how SQL Server chooses the order.

Does its arithmetic sequence changed whenever executed by SP?

Example of potential orders:

First execution :
group with value A under column XYZ = a + b + c + d

group with value B under column XYZ = a + c + d + b

Second execution :
group with value A under column XYZ = a + d + c + b

group with value B under column XYZ = b + c + d + a

Please provide the answer backed up with source material, like literature, guide, papers, etc.

Comment: if you want accuracy, don't use floating point. Use a fixed decimal type. The different answers you are getting is because some numbers cannot be represented in floating point not because floating point addition in axiomatically incorrect.

Comment: Are you asking about the `SUM` function? [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) seems to say (I am not familiar with it) that an *order-by_clause* determines the order. What are the “First execution” and the “Second execution” you describe? Are those actual observations of an SQL operation you performed or something you made up as hypothetical possibilities?

Comment: @mangerbang,  "float data type neither commutative ,,," --> Are you suggesting `a + b` does not always equal `b + a`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Well, NaNs will not always commute.

Comment: @eric Fair point.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Thank you for your answer,  actually I have already suggesting to cast that into numeric to my client. However, my client kind of skeptics about my suggestions because of my lack of evidence of why this sum of float causing unstable result. So, I need to understand of how sum calculate its additions to help me to prepare my evidence, since orders matters on float calculation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Actually, I just want to understand about how sum calculate the additions, how SQL determine its arithmetic sequence on each execution. Btw, I already read that material, but it didn't give me a clue about how sum calculate the order of its additions.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, for floating calculation. I just test it, it seems start to give a rounding error above 15 numbers of behind decimal point.

Comment: @mangerbang: “sum” is a generic word in English. Calculating a+b is a sum. That is why I asked whether you are specifically referring to the `SUM` operation in SQL Server, the specific function with that exact name, not to some sort of general calculation of additions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, I am referring to sum in SQL Server only. Those first and second execution is just some kind of hypotethical additional explanation to support my question : "Does its arithmetic sequence changed whenever executed by SP?" or should I say "Does the order of additions always changed whenever the sum is executed?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your all answer. I am very appreciate it. I almost found the concept of order of sum additions, it is located on the query plans.

SQL first sort it on each group. When I test it, on each group the data sort looks random > then processed it with stream aggregation.

```
--First enable "Include Actual Execution Plan" then run below query


CREATE TABLE #A (a int);
INSERT INTO #A (a) VALUES (1), (2);

CREATE TABLE #someFloats (val float);
INSERT INTO #someFloats (val) VALUES (1), (1), (1.234567), (1.2), (1.2), (3), 
(5);

SELECT #A.a, STR(SUM(#someFloats.val), 30, 25)
FROM #someFloats LEFT JOIN #A ON 1 = 1
GROUP BY #A.a;

--Look on execution plan, it mentions that it is sort by #A.a, then :
SELECT #A.a, #someFloats.val
FROM #someFloats LEFT JOIN #A ON 1 = 1
ORDER BY #A.a;

--Now we try to some based on above orders
Declare @A float = 1
Declare @B float = 1
Declare @C float = 1.234567
Declare @D float = 1.2
Declare @E float = 1.2
Declare @F float = 3
Declare @G float = 5

--The result is same
--#A.a = 1
select str((@A + @B +@C +@D +@E +@F +@G),30,15)

--#A.a = 2
select str((@G + @F +@D +@E +@C +@A +@B),30,15)

DROP TABLE #someFloats;
DROP TABLE #A;
```

It seems, Sum on SQL doing its addition comutatively (start from the first row of each group after being sort). No wonder, it gives different result on float calculation since orders matters, lol. I found it on this website, wish this help you all someday :D
(https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/showplan-operator-of-the-week-stream-aggregate/)

Answer (score 1):

To understand this, first you read the documentation's [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Nice, so now you know the precedence as well as the `left-to-right`ness shown in the text underneath.

Next step is to deduce the result's datatype. For each step, use an appropriate query. Eg, you know that first thing that will happen is `(a+b)`. You know the datatypes of a and b from your table (or previous steps). You can find out the resulting datatype from:

`exec sp_describe_first_result_set ('select a+b from yourtable')`

Now that you know the datatypes involved, it's study time. You mentioned floats, so you need to understand [floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic).

Or, if you have numeric/decimal, you'd need [fixed point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am very appreciate it. Gonna note this. :D

Answer (score 0):

Addition with float data type is both commutative and associative, within the normal margin of error for the float data type.

Practically speaking the results of any two executions of a floating point calculation can differ slightly due to different hardware execution.  Processors sometimes use 80bit floats internally.

Comment: This “answer” does not answer the question that was asked, which is how SQL Server calculates sums, particularly what order it uses.

Comment: The statement that addition is associative within the normal margin of error for the float data type is either wrong or useless. Consider `x+x-x-x+1`, where x is 2^1023. If this is associated as `((x+(x-x))-x)+1`, the result is 1, which equals the real-number arithmetic result, and there is no rounding error. If it is associated as `((((x+x)-x)-x)+1)`, the result is +∞. So either this answer is wrong that the result is always within the “normal” margin of error or the “normal” margin of error is infinite, which is useless.

Comment: Really, 2^1023? It’s a data type with a finite number of values, not a real number.  All data types misbehave at their max values.  If you go out of bounds in an intermediate calculation you get a wrong result.  But that happens with INT too.

Comment: Yes, really, 2^1023. It is representable in SQL’s `float` type and is entirely valid data for somebody to have. And, even without getting near the bounds of the type, the final error of a floating-point sum can vary greatly with different associations, so this answer is wrong or useless, as well as not addressing the question that was asked.

Comment: There are less than 2^300 atoms in the universe.

Comment: Counting objects is not the only thing people use numbers for. And, again, even avoiding the upper end of the floating-point range, the final error of a floating-pont sum can vary greatly with different associations. That is a real problem in real applications, and telling people it is “normal” does not solve their problems. This post does not answer the question that was asked, and the statement it makes is wrong or useless.

Comment: The other answer is the correct answer, but OP stated with confidence: "I know addition with float data type neither commutative nor associative", which is "float=bad" hysteria.  Float maintains ~15 significant digits of precision, and is less likely to overflow in intermediate results.  So it's the least squirrelly of all SQL Server's numeric data types for calculations.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thank you for the answer. However, after I am testing it on SQL server, it seems floating addition is not commutative, it is starting to show rounding errors above 15 digits behind decimal point. Just try this and change the order of additions

`select str(
((cast(1.2 as float)) + (cast(1.4 as float)) + (cast(1.6 as float)) + (cast(1.8 as float))
),38,25)
`

Floating additions is also not associative (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), please search using keyword "associative"

Comment: @EricPostpischil Actually you are correct and got my point ;D 
refers to : "This “answer” does not answer the question that was asked, which is how SQL Server calculates sums, particularly what order it uses."